# Shell script to read 2 files line by line and write common line to another file

Tags: shell, unix

file1.csv - carries a list of mobile numbers which are more than 100 thousands lines in below format;

```
447421475159,
447421475160,
447421475161,
447421475162,
447421475157,
447421475158,
447421475154,
447421475155,
447421475452,
447421475209,
```

file2.csv: carries around 1900 mobile numbers and is in same format as above.

I need to crosscheck the common lines in between both files and put it in a 3rd file.

Comment: It seems you forgot to include a question in your question.

Comment: see the `comm` command

Answer (score 1):

Using the unix command `comm`, which finds the common lines in two sorted files. Since your files are not sorted (judging from your post), you should also use the sort command. All together, use:

```
comm -12 <( sort file1.csv ) <( sort file2.csv ) > outputFile
```

Comment: what if number is not uniq in one of that file, in taht case output will not be useful

Comment: @vlp that was a good comment for my previous answer, but it was also wrong, because `uniq` assumes a sorted input. I found that `comm` better suits the needs of the OP though.

Answer (score 0):

this script

```
for i in `cat file2.csv`; do j=`grep $i file1.csv | wc -l`; if [[ $j -gt 0 ]]; then echo $i >> output.csv; fi; done
```

will take all number from file2.csv line by line and will compare it with file1.csv. If number from file2.csv is located in file1.csv at least one time, it will be writen in output.csv.

Answer (score -1):

try this

cat file1.csv |grep -f file2.csv

This prints all mobile numbers common between 2 files

sorry forget to add -f option

Comment: have you even try this? In my opinion your script will try to find file2.csv pattern in file1.csv and not content of file2.csv